MySQL problems with secure-file-priv
I am trying to run this SQL using MySQL Workbench
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/data.csv' INTO TABLE 
__dna_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(variant, variant_allele_count, total_allele_count, number_of_homozygotes, allele_frequency);

It returns this error
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Config file my.ini has secure-file-priv="". I have checked that this my.ini file is being used.
Database that MySQL Workbench is connected to is WordPress MySQL database on my local machine.

You should check the session level setting for secure file as opposed to the global one.

Run show global variables like 'secure_file_priv';

@ErgestBasha value in my.ini is "" and command returns NULL

@atricoky and the show session variables like 'secure_file_priv'; as I failed mentioned before , is it empty ?

and command returns NULL If a variable contains NULL then LOAD DATA is not allowed. Config file my.ini has secure-file-priv="". I have checked that this my.ini file is being used. It is possible that any other options file is loaded after my.ini, and this setting is reassigned in it. Also this setting can be reassigned in the service starting command line.
